# Use merge to combine shapefile and data to map using US zip codes

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, tigris

I'm trying to make a map based on zip codes in California, US.

Using the solution from my previous question ([How to create a map using zip codes in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76853631/how-to-create-a-map-using-zip-codes-in-r/76854006#76854006)), I obtained CA zip codes using:

```
library(tigris)
library(ggplot2)

zipcode <- zctas(year = 2000, state = "CA", cb = TRUE)
```

Then, I have my cleaned zip code file (named "ca") that has a column of zip codes and a column of count number, as integer.

I combined the two dataset using the following, zipcode goes first because that will save geometry.

```
zipcodes <- merge(zipcode, ca, by = "ZCTA", all.x = TRUE) %>%
  rename(COUNT = "Count")
```

Here's the code to plot:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = zipcodes, aes(fill = COUNT)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("red", "cornsilk", "#f0d080"),
                       values = c(1, 14150, 28307, na.value = "gray")) + #28307 is the max count.
  theme_minimal()
```

It's producing the following map, which doesn't seem to like my gradient code...

[image]

Some rows do have NA for COUNT because my dataset doesn't have a count for every zip, but I want to keep their geometry for the purpose of plotting a complete map.

When plotting, I also got the error message saying:

```
Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs (see `?scale_fill_gradientn`) `values`

> gives the position (**between 0 and 1**) for each colour in the colours vector.

Hence, you have to rescale the the vector passed to `values` to the range of 0 to 1, e.g. by dividing by the max value or using `scales::rescale(c(1, 14150, 28307))` which will also put the first value at the 0 position.

Besides that, you included the `na.value` in the `values` vector.

```r
library(tigris)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

zipcode <- zctas(year = 2000, state = "CA", cb = TRUE)

set.seed(123)

ca <- data.frame(
  ZCTA = sample(zipcode$ZCTA, 200),
  Count = sample(28307, 200)
)

zipcodes <- merge(zipcode, ca, by = "ZCTA", all.x = TRUE) %>%
  rename(COUNT = "Count")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = zipcodes, aes(fill = COUNT)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = c("red", "cornsilk", "#f0d080"),
    values = scales::rescale(c(1, 14150, 28307)),
    na.value = "gray"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]